# Different and Alternative Proofs of Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, lebesgue-integral

I am searching different and alternative proofs of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. i know that We may prove  this theorem by using Fatou Lemma ,with helping of Egorov theorem, Vitali Convergence theorem, Scheff's Lemma etc. I am already searching it  but you may suggest to me and give referrence  any **books or articles**  about this theorem. Do you have any different and orijinal ideas? You can also write your proofs. Thanks for your advices and answers.

Comment: Nice question! I only know Fatou, Egorov and Vitali proofs so I am very curious about other way to prove it. I will think about it tomorrow.

Comment: thanks:) good luck.